Parquet file: Nulls in DOUBLE data type causes SUM/AVG SQL aggregation issues
We have a small software that creates Parquet files like the attached:
https://canlogger1000.csselectronics.com/files/temp/null-not-working-as-expected.parquet
In this Parquet file, one of the columns have null values RearHitchPosition (as evident if you sort the column in e.g. the Tad Parquet viewer). These display as empty cells in Tad and as NaN in e.g. SQL queries like Amazon Athena. However, when we try to perform SQL query aggregations on the signal such as AVG or SUM, the aggregation fails to ignore the nulls.
This is also evident simply by opening the file in Tad and enabling column aggregations to be displayed. As evident, these do not work for columns with null values:

In contrast, if I create a Parquet file with pyarrow as per below script, the resulting Parquet can have nulls, while still enabling the aggregations to work:
https://canlogger1000.csselectronics.com/files/temp/null-working-as-expected.parquet
The script used is below:
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import math

# Replace these with your actual data for signal1 and signal2
timestamp_values = [1633010400000, 1633010401000, 1633010402000]  # Example timestamps in milliseconds
signal1_values = [10.5, 12.3, 11.7]  # Example data for Signal1
signal2_values = [None, 13.5, None]  # Example data for Signal2, where None represents missing values

# Check for NaN in signal2 and convert NaN to None (null)
# math.isnan() is used to check for NaN
cleaned_signal2_values = [None if x is None or math.isnan(x) else x for x in signal2_values]

# Define the schema with nullable fields
schema = pa.schema([
    ('timestamp', pa.timestamp('ms')),
    ('signal1', pa.float64()),
    ('signal2', pa.float64())
])

# Create the data dictionary
data = {
    'timestamp': timestamp_values,
    'signal1': signal1_values,
    'signal2': cleaned_signal2_values
}

# Create a PyArrow table
table = pa.Table.from_pydict(data, schema=schema)

# Write the table to a Parquet file
pq.write_table(table, 'output.parquet')


It seems like the schema used is slightly different, although Tad displays it as DOUBLE in both cases. It seems like the latter may be using some form of 'optional DOUBLE' schema.
We could of course change to the 'optional DOUBLE' schema in our tool instead to get around this, but we would prefer not to, as this seems to bloat the size of the Parquet and it would be a drastic change. Therefore we're wondering if there is an alternative way to get SQL tools like Amazon Athena to correctly "ignore" the null values, without having to create complex query filters?
